# How to format labels and form boxes when using django_filter

Tags: python, django

Very new here to django/python. I have a web page that makes use of django_filters for filtering a product view by category, and then orders them by price.  I am not sure how to actually format the output in the template.  Any help is appreciated:

views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post #indicating which model to use from models.py
    template_name = 'home.html' #specify which html file to use as the template
    context_object_name = 'all_posts_list' #Default: object_list
    ordering = ['price'] #reorder by price
    paginate_by = 16
    #queryset = Post.objects.all() #Default: Model.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = PostFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context
```

filters.py

```
    class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    CHOICES = (
        ('highToLow', 'Highest-to-Lowest'),
        ('lowToHigh', 'Lowest-to-Highest'),
    )

    ordering = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(label='Price', choices=CHOICES, method='filter_by_order')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['category']

    def filter_by_order(self, queryset, name, value):
        expression = 'price' if value == 'highToLow' else '-price'
        return queryset.order_by(expression)
```

html template

```
{% load bootstrap %}

{% block menubar %}
        <form class="form-inline" method="GET" style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">
          {{ filter.form|bootstrap }}
          &nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Go</button>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

[Template Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwWWp.png)

I am not sure how to actually format the labels and dropdowns being produced by the filter.form, other than adding the bootstrap |, which still does not help with spacing or alignment of labels.  Again, super new and any help appreciated, direction to further documentation, reading, etc...

Comment: Forms widget may be helpful in this scenario.. see -https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost same of how you doing `Form` customization.

`label` will be showed as label for the field, also you can use a customized `widget` and pass `placeholder, class` to control how the form looks.

```
from django.forms.widgets import Input

django_filters.CharFilter(label='name_starts', method=filter_name_starts, 
    widget = Input(attrs={'placeholder':'filter by first letter...', 'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Internally, `Filter` class hold a default form `Field` as a class attribute,  paramters defined on the `Filter` related to form are passed to form `Field` to render the HTML.

Then consult to [Manually render django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually), then you can customize the form looks in field level

#### EDIT

`ChoiceFilter` is kind of special here, if you would like to change the [empty_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label) of the category, you need add a new line.

```
    CHOICES = (
        ('', '----'), # replace the value '----' with your values, served just like placeholder in CharField
        ('highToLow', 'Highest-to-Lowest'),
        ('lowToHigh', 'Lowest-to-Highest'),
    )
```

#### UPDATED

if you use `class Meta`: you can not override widgets in the definition time, in this case. you can do some adjustments after the filter initialized.note, this also works for other `ChoiceFilter`

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # change the widget choices after initialization
        self.form.fields['category'].widget.choices = [("", "please select a value"),] + list(self.form.fields["category"].choices)[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks that did help with the formatting, however Input removed the dropdown filter and just replaced it with a text input field.  So, while this did format the field effectively, it also deactivated the purpose of the field, which was a sort by price dropdown.  Any thoughts on how to get the dropdown back, maintaining the formatting?

Comment: was able to figure out using Select instead of Input brought back the dropdown choices and maintained formatting.  widget = Select(attrs...

Comment: I am still not able to access the category field and format it.  any ideas?

Comment: thanks for the help.  That worked on the ChoiceFilter.  Can you also assist on helping me to understand how to format 'category', in the above code.  I will attach an image of what is now rendering with the current code.  The ChoiceFilter is formatted, but the 'category' dropdown is not.

Comment: @JustinScambray test if it works, and happy coding :)